# Clearing app data when creating base line profiles

Tags: android, baseline-profile

I'm trying to create some baseline profiles for my Android app that are a bit more meaningful than simply `startActivityAndWait()`

My app starts off in an uninitialised state but once the user has chosen a destination this is stored in DataStore Preferences and you then no longer see the initial screens.

This means that running the BaselineProfileRule for the subsequent iterations fail because the initial buttons etc. are no longer applicable.

Is there a way to clear the app data between test runs with the BaselineProfile tests? I've tried adding `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("adb shell pm clear *packageName*")` in the test but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried adding `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'` to the benchmark build.gradle but this was also ineffective.

Comment: Its been reported - lets see if this is one of those issues that will take years to fix...

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259388454

Answer (score 3):

A workaround I've been using to handling this is

```
fun MacrobenchmarkScope.isFirstIteration() = iteration == 0
```

And then, inside setup block:

```
if (isFirstIteration()) {
    pressHome()
    startActivityAndWait()
    //Login
    killProcess()
}
```

Comment: It should be `iteration == 1` for the first iteration

Comment: Oh, wait, it's 1 for `BaselineProfileRule` and 0 for `MacrobenchmarkRule`